# missing apps icons on dock after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dock

Few weeks after installing 18.04, I decided to upgrade to 19.04.

After the upgrade process was finished I found all the apps icons on the dock disappeared, except the '*Show Applications*' button.

[image]

I've tried to reinstall dash to dock extension from tweaks, but nothing changed.

Is there anything else to get my dock back to normal?

Comment: I have the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04. After reboot icons appear again, but after some minutes, they are gone.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here. I installed plank and dash to plank gnome shell extension and disable dash to dock and Ubuntu dock. Not a fix but allows you to have a dock that mimics Ubuntu dock, with the added value of animations.[image: plank dock]